# Error while parsing JSON Object in Java Android

Tags: android, json, android-arrayadapter, android-json

In my Android app, I am fetching the details of Points table of a tournament to convert the output to a string from JSON object to Java

JSON object is shown below:

```
{
  "group": {
    "Teams": [
      {
        "name": "Team 1",
        "p": "10",
        "w": "9",
        "l": "1",
        "points": "18"
      },
      {
        "name": "Team 2",
        "p": "10",
        "w": "9",
        "l": "1",
        "points": "18"
      },
      {
        "name": "Team 3",
        "p": "10",
        "w": "9",
        "l": "1",
        "points": "18"
      },
      {
        "name": "Team 4",
        "p": "10",
        "w": "6",
        "l": "4",
        "points": "12"
      },
      {
        "name": "Team 5",
        "p": "10",
        "w": "6",
        "l": "4",
        "points": "12"
      },
      {
        "name": "Team 6",
        "p": "10",
        "w": "6",
        "l": "4",
        "points": "12"
      },
      {
        "name": "Team 7",
        "p": "10",
        "w": "5",
        "l": "5",
        "points": "11"
      },
      {
        "name": "Team 8",
        "p": "10",
        "w": "5",
        "l": "5",
        "points": "11"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Android Java Code is below:

```
JSONObject match = new JSONObject(response);

if (match.has("group")) {
    JSONObject group = match.getJSONObject("group");

    if (match.has("Teams")) {
        JSONObject teams = group.getJSONObject("Teams");

        if (teams.has("0")) {
            JSONObject teams_object = teams.getJSONObject("0");
            String team_name = teams_object.getString("name");
            String matches_played = teams_object.getString("p");
            String matches_won = teams_object.getString("w");
            String matches_lost = teams_object.getString("l");
            String points = teams_object.getString("points");
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting the error where I print the error message through getMessage() method. Here is the error below:

```
Error: Value ["name","p","w","l","points"] at header of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Can anyone please help like where I am going wrong or what is the fix ? Thanks in advance

Comment: http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/Convert

Comment: use POJO classes. Parsing will be much more easy

Comment: check my answer @SaAsh

Comment: Checking @g.brahmaDatta

Comment: Team should be Json array. not a Json Object.

Comment: yeah if you find any problem you can ping i will solve it @SaAshTechs

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta, I am getting the error 'Cannot resolve method getJSONArray(java.lang.String)'

Comment: did you try my edited answer? @SaAshTechs.I have wrote group instead of teams

Comment: Ahh, sorry , my fault

Comment: Just try it. I didn't try in my code. I have just written it without checking @SaAshTechs

Comment: I still see the same error Sir @g.brahmaDatta

Comment: I will check it @SaAshTechs

Comment: check my edited answer @SaAshTechs . I made a mistake.Now you will not get error

Comment: But sir, I am still getting the same error as I gave in my question @g.brahmaDatta

Comment: @SaAshTechs check my answer it is working at my side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: I have edited my answer by using the same format of your answer just check it @SaAshTechs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 4 mistakes in your code,

1.You have to check whether `group` has `teams` instead `match` has `teams`.

2.You have to get `team` as `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject` because it is array.

3.You have to check the size of team, instead of find the object with key `0`, there is no object with name `0` in your group,

4.You have to get the object based on index instead of key(ie., `0`)

Please check the working code, this is tested

```
try {
    JSONObject  match = new JSONObject(response);
    if (match.has("group")) {
        JSONObject group = match.getJSONObject("group");

        if (group.has("Teams")) {
            JSONArray teams = group.getJSONArray("Teams");

            if (teams.length() > 0) {
                JSONObject teams_object =(JSONObject) teams.get(0);
                String team_name = teams_object.getString("name");
                String matches_played = teams_object.getString("p");
                String matches_won = teams_object.getString("w");
                String matches_lost = teams_object.getString("l");
                String points = teams_object.getString("points");
                Log.v(TAG, team_name);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Json Teams holds the Array of Object and you are parsing wrong.
Try this

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
 JSONObject groups = jsonObject.getJSONObject("group");
 JSONArray teams = groups.getJSONArray("Teams");
 for(int i=0;i<teams.length();i++){
        JSONObject obj = teams.getJSONObject(i);
        name.append(obj.getString("name")+"\n");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, I am getting the error 'Cannot resolve method getJSONArray(java.lang.String)'  @Rajnish suryavanshi

Comment: what string name you are passing?

Comment: check my updated code. I checked and I am getting output as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this @SaAsh, I have just edited by taking your answer

```
if (match.has("group")) {
JSONObject group = match.getJSONObject("group");

if (match.has("Teams")) {
    JSONObject teams = group.getJsonArray("Teams");


        for(int i = 0 ; i < teams.length();i++){
        JSONObject teams_object = teams.getJSONObject("i");
        String team_name = teams_object.getString("name");
        String matches_played = teams_object.getString("p");
        String matches_won = teams_object.getString("w");
        String matches_lost = teams_object.getString("l");
        String points = teams_object.getString("points");
      }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you passing any header type while calling it to server? @SaAshTechs

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
    JSONObject subObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("group") ;
    JSONArray jsonArray = subObject.getJSONArray("Teams");
    for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
        String p= jsonObject.getString("p");
        String w= jsonObject.getString("w");
        String l= jsonObject.getString("l");
        String points = jsonObject.getString("points");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @SaAshTechs Share your logcat, then I will be able to help you out and full activity code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (match.has("group")) {
    JSONObject group = match.getJSONObject("group");

    if (match.has("Teams")) {
        JSONArray teams = group.getJSONArray("Teams");

     // for only 0th element use below code else looping

                JSONObject teams_object = (JSONObject) teams.get(0);
                String team_name = teams_object.getString("name");
                String matches_played = teams_object.getString("p");
                String matches_won = teams_object.getString("w");
                String matches_lost = teams_object.getString("l");
                String points = teams_object.getString("points");

    }
}
```

Comment: @SaAshTechs better you go for gson parsing

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Value ["name","p","w","l","points"] at header of type
>   org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

You are getting the error because there is an Array of Teams and you are trying parse with `JSONObject`

Please check below code snippet. It will work.

```
try {
        JSONObject match = new JSONObject("your_response");
        if (match.has("group")) {
            JSONObject group = match.getJSONObject("group");

            if (group.has("Teams")) {
                JSONArray teams = group.getJSONArray("Teams");

                for(int i=0; i < teams.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject teams_object = (JSONObject) teams.get(i);
                    String team_name = teams_object.getString("name");
                    String matches_played = teams_object.getString("p");
                    String matches_won = teams_object.getString("w");
                    String matches_lost = teams_object.getString("l");
                    String points = teams_object.getString("points");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @SaAshTechs Update your question with latest code, JSON and error